# How to solve this problem without using recursion? (Number of ways a line can be arranged with restriction)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good day! I am currently writing a code that solves the way in which a line with n number of people with varying heights can be arranged so that m number of people can see "with no obstruction". A person is "with no obstruction" when all the people in front of that person is shorter than the person itself.

I answered this by using recursion:

```
def notObstruct(n, m):
    if n == 0 and m == 0: return 0
    if m == 0 and n >= 1: return 0
    if m == n: return 1
    if m > n: return 0
    
    return notObstruct(n-1, m-1) + (n-1) * notObstruct(n-1, m)
```

I used stirling number of the first kind to solve this problem. However, I need to solve this using permutation and combination as a restriction from the problem itself.

```
notObstruct(5, 3) = 35
notObstruct(7, 2) = 1764
notObstruct(10, 3) = 1172700
```

Comment: It is noted that the tallest is always "Not Obstructed". I have to get all the possible ways a line can be formed with EXACTLY m number of people "not obstructed"